# kafka strimzi use my own certificate Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, strimzi

I am trying to set up using my GoDaddy certificate as a listener for Kafka. Using this article https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/in-development/using.html#kafka-listener-certificates-str.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: es-kafka-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.7.0
    replicas: 2
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: tls
        configuration:  
          brokerCertChainAndKey:
            secretName: es-tls-certificate
            certificate: certificate.crt
            key: certificate.key
    authorization:
      type: simple
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      log.message.format.version: "2.7"
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 2
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  entityOperator:
    userOperator: {}
    topicOperator: {}
```

I am sending a check for a certificate openssl s_client -connect MY_IP:9094 -servername MY_IP

Returns my correct certificate.
But when I try to execute the command I get an error

```
 kafkacat -C -b MY_IP:9094 -X security.protocol=ssl -t schedules
% ERROR: Failed to query metadata for topic schedules: Local: Timed out
```

Log from Kafka

```
(SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    authentication:
      type: tls
```

Authentication TLS seems to state your client need to authenticate with mtls, try the following command and post and update please

kafkacat -b MY_IP:9094 
-X security.protocol=SSL -X ssl.key.location=private_key.pem -X ssl.key.password=my_key_password 
-X ssl.certificate.location=signed_cert.pem.txt 
-X ssl.ca.location=ca_cert.pem -L

Or remove the authentication clause

And add to kafkacat

-X ssl.ca.location=ca_cert.pem

Comment: thanks for your ansver) I get an error ```invalid type for io.strimzi.kafka.v1beta2.Kafka.spec.kafka.listeners.authentication: got "string", expected "map"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with validate=false
```

Comment: Try totally remove the authentication section, what happens?

Comment: thanks the deployment worked in Kubernetes. Now I get an error In my test Linux machine
 kafkacat -C -b IP:9094 -X security.protocol=ssl -t schedules
% ERROR: Topic schedules error: Broker: Topic authorization failed

Comment: and from My application sasl_ssl://IP:9094/bootstrap: SSL handshake failed: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed: broker certificate could not be verified, verify that ssl.ca.location is correctly configured or root CA certificates are installed (add broker's CA certificate to the Windows Root certificate store)

Comment: -X ssl.ca.location=ca_cert.pem

Comment: thanks) New erroe kafkacat -C -b IP:9094 -X security.protocol=ssl -X ssl.ca.location=mycert.pem -t schedules
% ERROR: Failed to query metadata for topic schedules: Local: Broker transport failure

Comment: -d protocol,feature,broker (and post the logs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233290/discussion-between-vitalii-fedorenko-and-ran-lupovich).